# How can I rotate this matrix around the center?

Tags: c#, xna, physics, farseer

My XNA game uses Farseer Physics, which is a 2d physics engine with an optional renderer for physics engine data, to help you debug. Visual debug data is very useful, so I have it setup to be drawn according to my camera's state. This works perfectly, except for z axis rotation. See, I have a camera class that supports movement, zoom, and z axis rotation. My debug class uses the Farseer's debug renderer to create matrices that make the debug data be drawn according to the camera, and it does it well, except for one thing.. the z axis rotation uses the top-left corner of the screen for (0, 0), while my camera rotates using the center of the viewport as (0, 0). Does anyone have any tips for me? If I can make the debug drawer rotate from the center, it would work perfectly with my camera.

```
        public void Draw(Camera2D camera, GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)
    {
        // Projection (location and zoom)
        float width = (1f / camera.Zoom) * ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(graphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2);
        float height = (-1f / camera.Zoom) * ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(graphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2);
        //projection = Matrix.CreateOrthographic(width, height, 1f, 1000000f);
        projection = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(
            -width,
            width,
            -height,
            height,
            0f, 1000000f);

        // View (translation and rotation)
        float xTranslation = -1 * ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(camera.Position.X);
        float yTranslation = -1 * ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(camera.Position.Y);
        Vector3 translationVector = new Vector3(xTranslation, yTranslation, 0f);
        view = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(camera.Rotation) * Matrix.Identity;
        view.Translation = translationVector;

        DebugViewXNA.RenderDebugData(ref projection, ref view);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One common approach to solving these sort of issues is to move the object in question to the 'centre', rotate and the move it back.
So in this case, I'd suggest applying a transformation that moves the camera "up and across" by half the screen dimensions, apply the rotation and then move it back.

Comment: I've tried that, but it still seems to rotate around the top-left corner. Maybe I'm misunderstanding; could I see a code snippet perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

In general, in order to perform rotation around point (x, y, z), the operation needs to be broken down into 3 conceptual parts:

1. T is a translation matrix that translates by (-x, -y, -z)
2. R is a rotation matrix that rotates around the relevant axis.
3. T^-1 is the matrix that translates back to (x, y, z)

The matrix you're after is the result of the multiplication of these 3, in reverse order:

M = T^-1 * R ^ T

The x,y,z you should use are your camera's position.